# Word VBA: ConvertToShape method makes image disappear

Tags: vba, ms-word

I wrote some code for a client which isn't working correctly on his machine (Win 10, Office 365) but is on mine (Win 10, Office 2016). The code inserts an image to the header then positions it and resizes it. I use the ConvertToShape method so I can access properties like width, height and position of the Shape class.

```
Dim pic As Shape
Dim shp As Word.InlineShape

Set shp = thisDocument.Sections.Item(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(fpImage) ' insert the image to the header

Set pic = shp.ConvertToShape ' THIS LINE CAUSES THE PROBLEM
```

The method causes the image to disappear. 'Pic' is still available and setting it's properties causes no error, but it is not visible. It's .visible property returns true.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Negative 1 *is* `True`, so the Shape.Visible is already true.  Is it the only shape in the header?

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860737.aspx I'll amend the post. Yes, it's the only shape in the header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer provided to cross-post at [Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-msoffice_custom/word-vba-converttoshape-method-makes-image/900c4e6d-23e3-4c84-a5ad-4b47e8c9d848)

There is a way to do this with only an inline shape, by setting up a table to position the text on the left and the picture on the right. An additional advantage of this method is that, if you set the table's AutoFitBehavior property to wdAutoFitFixed and set the column width to the width you want for the shape, Word will automatically resize the picture to that width and keep the aspect ratio.

Here's a little sample macro:

```
Sub x()
   Dim fpImage As String
   Dim strExistingHeaderText
   Dim tbl As Table
   Dim shp As InlineShape

   fpImage = "D:\Pictures\bunnycakes.jpg"

   With ActiveDocument
      strExistingHeaderText = _
         .Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text

      Set tbl = .Tables.Add( _
         Range:=.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range, _
         numrows:=1, numcolumns:=2, _
         AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed)
      tbl.Columns(2).Width = InchesToPoints(1.5)
      tbl.Columns(1).Width = InchesToPoints(5#)
      tbl.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = strExistingHeaderText
      'tbl.Borders.Enable = False

      Set shp = tbl.Cell(1, 2).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(fpImage)
   End With
End Sub
```